# mkmapview not search all the places that are written in search bar

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uisearchbar

mkmapview not search all the places that are written in search bar like any address of city ... its shown in autocomplete search bar and in tableview but when i click on that place its not search ...

https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

please solve my problem ....`enter code here`

```
       {


            // THIS IS NOT THE CODE 
            its just written because of question is not uploaded


            SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *query = [SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery query];
        query.input = @"185 berry str";
        query.radius = 100.0;
         query.language = @"en";
              query.types = SPPlaceTypeGeocode; // Only return geocoding (address) results.
            query.location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.76999, -122.44696);
           }
```

Comment: not search all the places ... its search only main main place like city state only .....

Comment: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=%@&key=%@"